# Direct method failing when using Azure IOT Direct methods

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am currently using the azure-iot-sdk-c on the TI CC-3235 microcontroller. I tried using the Azure Direct methods to invoke a method (blinkLED1) on the microcontroller. Azure IoT hub gives me an error saying "not registered" like below:
`{"message":"Device {\"Message\":\"{\\\"errorCode\\\":404103,\\\"trackingId\\\":\\\"c1763a63a5b54381aa555198de1e884c-TimeStamp:07/01/2020 12:03:39\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"Timed out waiting for device to connect.\\\",\\\"info\\\":{\\\"timeout\\\":\\\"00:03:45\\\"},\\\"timestampUtc\\\":\\\"2020-07-01T12:03:39.1927271Z\\\"}\",\"ExceptionMessage\":\"\"} not registered"}`

The code below is a modification of the example code from TI/Microsoft. The microcontroller C code is below:

```
{
    (void)userContextCallback;
    (void)payload;
    Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "\r\nDevice Method called");
    Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "Device Method name:    %s", method_name);
    Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "Device Method payload: %.*s", (int)size, (const char*)payload);

    int status = 200;
    char* RESPONSE_STRING = "{ \"Response\": \"This is the response from the device\" }";
    Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "\r\nResponse status: %d", status);
    Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "Response payload: %s\r\n", RESPONSE_STRING);
    if(strcmp("blinkLED1",method_name)==0){
        const char deviceMethodResponse[] = "{\"Response\":\"LED Blink1 Received\"}";
        Display_printf(display, 0, 0, "\r\nDevice Method called");
        *resp_size = sizeof(deviceMethodResponse)-1;
        *response = malloc(*resp_size);
        (void)memcpy(*response, deviceMethodResponse, *resp_size);
        status = 200;
    }
    *resp_size = strlen(RESPONSE_STRING);
    if ((*response = malloc(*resp_size)) == NULL)
    {
        status = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        (void)memcpy(*response, RESPONSE_STRING, *resp_size);
    }
    g_continueRunning = false;
    return status;
}
```

TI Example reference:[iothub_client_sample_device_method](https://dev.ti.com/tirex/explore/node?node=ANXoNQGeQjExMVJXpE5vjg__9QUeYYT__LATEST)

Azure IoT SDK C Reference :[Run a simple device Twin C sample on Windows](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/tree/master/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_device_twin_and_methods_sample)

Comment: This `Timed out waiting for device to connect` and `not registered` message suggests that there is a problem with either connectivity or registration of your device.

What is the status of the device on the IoT Hub level?

Comment: I am able to receive telemetry data and is shown in azure metrics

Comment: What is the method name you are passing from Azure Portal to call direct method. DeviceMethodCallback  #81 handles that. May be you can tweak the code to check to check if call is made with correct MethodName.

Comment: I am calling the blinkLED1 from the azure portal. The blinkLED1 function is present in the microcontroller code.

Comment: @PranavMP, Just checking back, is this issue consistent or transient?

Comment: @SatishBoddu-MSFT Yup, its consistent